# Android gson.toJson() gives a result with escaped quotes (\")

Tags: java, android, gson

I use Gson to serialize my object, but the result contains many '\"' which should be '"', like:

```
{"data":"{\"calldate\":\"2012-05-03 00:12:00\",\"id\":0,\"uid\":0,\"popdbid\":0
,\"mobilesqlid\":1336025277424,\"callstatus\":2,\"checkstatus\":0,\"resultstatus
\":0,\"sequence\":0,\"subbrandstatus\":0,\"subcategorystatus\":0,\"synstatus\":1
,\"targetstatus\":0,\"trackstatus\":0,\"isfrommobile\":0}","user":{"id":11,"ente
rprise_id":1}}
```

This is the code I use to serialize:

```
GsonBuilder builder=new GsonBuilder();
builder.setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd mm:hh:ss");
builder.excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation();
Gson gson=builder.create();
String gsonString = gson.toJson(callDayPlanning);
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: It doesn't look like a string returned by gson.toJosn() to me. How did you create this string? Post some code would help.

Comment: GsonBuilder builder=new GsonBuilder();
builder.setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd mm:hh:ss");
builder.excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation();
Gson gson=builder.create();
String gsonString = gson.toJson(callDayPlanning);

Comment: Sorry for the format, I am learning on it.

Comment: please post your object class also if possible because when i check with sample object class then its work fine.

Comment: This looks like the `data` field in whatever `callDayPlanning` is, contains a JSON string already instead of an object graph that still needs to be serialized to JSON.

Answer (score 0):

As @PhilippReichart stated, your `callDayPlanning` contains (probably) a `String` field named `data` that contains a Json string. This is confirmed by [json.parser.online.fr](http://json.parser.online.fr/):
[image].

There's nothing wrong to put a Json string as payload of another object but it will be escaped. But, if you want that `data` would be the serialization of another object (whose class is named `DayPlanning` maybe?) you have to change `data` type from `String` to your custom class.